# How to drag and drop multiple points in geotools on map

Tags: java, geotools

I want to drag and drop multiple points in geotools.
I know how to select multiple points but unable drag them to different location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

GeoTools has no built in drag and drop functionality for features. You would need to write your own, probably by extending the `MapMouseAdapter` and adding a custom [`tool`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported/swing/src/main/java/org/geotools/swing/tool).

If you get it working we'd love a [contribution](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/procedures/contribute.html) back to the project.